# Setting text to a custom dialog class

Tags: java, android

I am trying to build a custom Dialog that I am setting the text Dynamically. Here is my code that is throwing a `NullPointerException`. **UPDATAED CODE**

```
  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            HomeItem homeItem = (HomeItem) adapter.getItem(position);
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(databaseFightCard.this, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
            WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = (dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
            lp.dimAmount = 0.5f;
            dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);

            Window window = dialog.getWindow();
            window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) databaseFightCard.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           RelativeLayout relative = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null, false);

            Button play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bPlay);
            Button done = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bDone);
            TextView rn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRName);
            TextView ra = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRAge);
            TextView rr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRRecord);
            TextView rh = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRHeight);
            TextView rw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRWeight);
            TextView rc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRCity);
            TextView re = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRExp);
            TextView bn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBName);
            TextView ba = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBAge);
            TextView br = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBRecord);
            TextView bh = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBHeight);
            TextView bw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBWeight);
            TextView bc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBCity);
            TextView be = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBExp);


            rn.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemRedName()+"");
            ra.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemRedAge()+"");
            rr.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemRedRecord()+"");
            rh.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemRedHeight()+"");
            rw.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemRedWeight()+"");
            rc.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemRedCity()+"");
            re.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemRedExp()+"");
            bn.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemBlueName()+"");
            ba.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemBlueAge()+"");
            br.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemBlueRecord()+"");
            bh.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemBlueHeight()+"");
            bw.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemBlueWeight()+"");
            bc.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemBlueCity()+"");
            be.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemBlueExp()+"");
            dialog.setContentView(relative);

            play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //add the play intent here
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
                dialog.show();

        }
    });
```

I am getting NullPointerException on

```
rn.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemRedName()+"");
```

Please explain how I can set the text to my Dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try showing your dialog first, as in, put dialog.show before you try to find the textViews. Either that, or inflate your view first and pass the view to the dialog. What you're doing now is trying to find the view before it's inflated.

Edit: To use the inflator, try this,

```
   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

   RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null, false);

   TextView rn = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvRName);

   dialog.setContentView(view);
```

Edit 2:

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        HomeItem homeItem = (HomeItem) adapter.getItem(position);
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(databaseFightCard.this, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = (dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
        lp.dimAmount = 0.5f;
        dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);

        Window window = dialog.getWindow();
        window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) databaseFightCard.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       RelativeLayout relative = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null, false);

        dialog.setContentView(relative);

        Button play = (Button) relative.findViewById(R.id.bPlay);
        Button done = (Button) relative.findViewById(R.id.bDone);
        TextView rn = (TextView) relative.findViewById(R.id.tvRName);
        TextView ra = (TextView) relative.findViewById(R.id.tvRAge);
        TextView rr = (TextView) relative.findViewById(R.id.tvRRecord);
        TextView rh = (TextView) relative.findViewById(R.id.tvRHeight);
        TextView rw = (TextView) relative.findViewById(R.id.tvRWeight);
        TextView rc = (TextView) relative.findViewById(R.id.tvRCity);
        TextView re = (TextView) relative.findViewById(R.id.tvRExp);
        TextView bn = (TextView) relative.findViewById(R.id.tvBName);
        TextView ba = (TextView) relative.findViewById(R.id.tvBAge);
        TextView br = (TextView) relative.findViewById(R.id.tvBRecord);
        TextView bh = (TextView) relative.findViewById(R.id.tvBHeight);
        TextView bw = (TextView) relative.findViewById(R.id.tvBWeight);
        TextView bc = (TextView) relative.findViewById(R.id.tvBCity);
        TextView be = (TextView) relative.findViewById(R.id.tvBExp);


        rn.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemRedName()+"");
        ra.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemRedAge()+"");
        rr.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemRedRecord()+"");
        rh.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemRedHeight()+"");
        rw.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemRedWeight()+"");
        rc.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemRedCity()+"");
        re.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemRedExp()+"");
        bn.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemBlueName()+"");
        ba.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemBlueAge()+"");
        br.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemBlueRecord()+"");
        bh.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemBlueHeight()+"");
        bw.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemBlueWeight()+"");
        bc.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemBlueCity()+"");
        be.setText(homeItem.getHomeItemBlueExp()+"");
        dialog.setContentView(relative);

        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //add the play intent here
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
            dialog.show();

    }
});
```

Comment: I already tried to put my .show() first. I don't know how to do the other thing you say.

Comment: When would be the best time to `setText`? before or after `dialog.setContentView(view);`

Comment: It doesn't matter when you setText, just as long as the layout has been inflated.

Comment: Your code will produce this error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout`

Comment: Sorry, I updated the edit. I assumed your root layout was a FrameLayout, but it's a RelativeLayout.

Comment: Alright, Still getting a nullPointer on the same line. I updated my code

Comment: See my second edit, the inflated layout needs to be added to the dialog view and when finding widget ids, you need to reference the layout.